# Why is my account usage taking only half the used RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-leaks

I've been suffering from this issue for the longest time and I can't seem to find a solution, as you can see, my account is using 31% but the total usage is 67%, and it's worse on startup (using less than 5% and total is 55%)

[image]

Tried multiple solutions for memory leak, namely :

- Updated all my drivers
- Updated Windows
- Scanned for malware with Windows Defender and MalwareBytes
- Used memory diag tool, nothing was found
- Uninstalled all non essential programs

Nothing seems to work, here's the overall RAM consumption :

[image]

Comment: What is your actual problem? Is something not working? Are you trying to account for all the memory used?

Comment: There are lots of questions on this site about Windows using more ram than the user expects was well. I recommend reviewing these as there is a good chance they may contain the answer you are looking for: https://superuser.com/search?q=Windows+using+ram